# Execute code once html has loaded with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to run some code when an html page has been loaded into my page using Ajax as follows:

```
$( ".content" ).load("game.html");
```

I would like to perform actions when that html has finished loading, how is it done please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach a callback function,

```
$( ".content" ).load("game.html", function(){
    //YOUR CODE TO EXECUTE
    alert('completed');
});
```

Check jQuery Documentation for more information, http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".content" ).load("game.html", function() {
    // add your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [read the documentation on the .load() method](http://api.jquery.com/load/), you will see that it allows you to provide a callback function that will be called when the load is complete.

```
$(".content").load("game.html", function() {
    //put your code that you want to run here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the jQuery docs?

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#result').load('game.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback for that:

```
$( ".content" ).load("game.html",function(e){
    // use e, like $(e).find("#some-id")
});
```